# Configuring DNS entry on unix for SQL Azure with DataDirect6.1

Tags: unix, odbc, azure-sql-database, aix, informatica-powercenter

Could you please advise me, how to configure a DSN entry for SQL Azure on UNix AIX box with DataDirect 6.1 to connect from PowerCenter 9.1.0.

Aix Server: 10.10.10.10 : 2222
On this Port, ABCXYZ9PQR(Database Server name) Database is configured.
Database name: TestDatabase

Telent is working from application server. Telnet 10.10.10.10 2222 --> Connected
Able to connect to the SQL server from Windows.

Please advise me what are the tests do I need to perform, and configure the DSN entry in ODBC.ini.

Thanks,
Sarat

Answer (score 0):

Below steps are necessary for configuring odbc:

- Ensure that the env variables ODBCHOME & ODBCINI are set. These has to be set before Informatica Services are started. Else they wont get picked up.
- configure DNS in obdc.ini file for the DB server.
- Use ssgbodbc utility (download from mysupport site) to test if the odbc connection goes through
- Copy the DNS name from the entry in odbc.ini variable and paste it in the Connection String section of the ODBC connection in Workflow Manager.

I'm not clear from your description though:

Can you clarify if the Informatica Services is installed on AIX box (10.10.10.10)? how did you configure the connection to azure on windows box?

-Sadagopan

Comment: Hi Sadagopan, Infa Service is running on 20.20.20.20. SQL Azure is configured on 10.10.10.10,2222 with dabase server name as abcxyz9pq.
[TEST3]
Driver=/Infa/9.1.0/ODBC6.1/lib/DWmsss25.so
Description=DataDirect 6.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol
Server=10.10.10.10,2222
AlternateServers=
AnsiNPW=Yes
ConnectionRetryCount=0
ConnectionRetryDelay=3
Database=TestDrive
LoadBalancing=0
LogonID=
Password=
QuotedId=No
ReportCodePageConversionErrors=0

Comment: SSGODBC Output: ./ssgodbc -d TEST3 -u username@abcxyz9pq.database.windows.net -p password -v Error for thread 0 {error} STATE=08001, CODE=47513313464, MSG=[Informatica][ODBC SQL Server Legacy Driver][libssclient25]General network error. Check your network documentation.

Comment: I dont think informatica provides odbc drivers for Sql Azure. But they do support any type-2 odbc drivers. so you may try the drivers that data direct provide for sql azure. Try the URL http://www.datadirect.com/products/odbc/sql-azure/index.html